# Primitive root, if and only if condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is the easiest way to see that $a \not\equiv 0, 1 \text{ (mod }p\text{)}$ is a primitive root mod odd $p$ if and only if for all $q$ such that $q|(p-1)$, we have$$a^{{p-1}\over{q}} \not\equiv 1 \text{ (mod }p\text{)}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the order of $a$ modulo $p$ is defined as the least $k$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Recall also that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ precisely when the order of $a$ modulo $p$ is $p-1$.

We know from Fermat's Little Theorem that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Thus, the order of $a$ modulo $p$ divides $p-1$. Let's call this order $k$.

So we know that $k \mid p-1$. Can you show that, given this, we have $k < p-1$ if, and only if, $k \mid \frac{p-1}{q}$ for some prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$?

> $k \mid p-1$ means that there exists $m$ with $mk = p-1$.
>
>  $k < p-1$ precisely when $m > 1$.
>
>  But then $m$ must have some prime factor $q$. 
>
>
>  This means that $\frac{m}{q} k = \frac{p-1}{q}$, in other words that $k \mid \frac{p-1}{q}$